# How to set 1st date on dynamic selected month in datepicker?

Tags: php, html

I want to enable the datepicker after selected month in datepicker and this is done by using `**data-date-start-date="<?php echo $month;?>"**` and this is done. but date enable from current month date so i want to start dates from 1st date of the month.

```html
<div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="input-group input-medium date-picker input-daterange datepicker" data-date="01/11/2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date-start-date="-<?php echo $last_salary_mnth;?>m">
        <input type="text" name="leave_from" id="leave_from" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['leave_from'])) { echo $_POST['leave_from'];}else{ echo date('d-m-Y');} ?>" onchange='Calculate_day(<?php echo json_encode($array_holiday_rows); ?>)' class="form-control" placeholder="From" autocomplete="off" required>
        <span class="input-group-addon"> to </span>
        <input type="text" name="leave_to" id="leave_to" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['leave_to'])) { echo $_POST['leave_to'];}else{ echo date('d-m-Y');} ?>" onchange='Calculate_day(<?php echo json_encode($arrayenter code here_holiday_rows); ?>)' class="form-control" placeholder="To" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <span class="help-block" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">DD-MM-YYYY</span>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Thanks Aroon for rearranging code